# API Managment new installation

Tags: mysql, wso2

We are installing a new environment for WSO2 API managment on Linux servers and Mysql 5.7 DB. One server intend to be the Publisher and the other one the Gateway.

I read the installtion guide, but i couldn't figured out what is the best practice to work with the databases. Since there are several db's : apimgtdb, userdb, regdb and statdb, should we create one db for all of them? or a better way to seperate?

which script should we use? i saw two under:

WSO2AM-2.1.0\DBSCRIPTS\mysql5.7.sql
WSO2AM-2.1.0\DBSCRIPTS\APIMGT\mysql5.7.sql

Please advise..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to have separate databases. You can find a complete guide [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+an+Active-Active+Deployment).

Comment: @OdedLiberman really you may rather follow the guide. Some databases may/should be separated, some needs to be shared (api, user)